# how to upload user profile image into sql database from any local c or d drive or any folder of the system using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

when i am clicking the submit button for inserting user details i want to upload a image of the user profile picture into the sql database. i write the code for only take the image from a particular d-folder to upload the image here i write code to upload the image but getting error ( u.setImage(5, (InputStream)fs1, fs1.available());)
And also i want to upload the image from any drive of the system and stored into sql database.

Servlet Coding:

```
        @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Insert"})
    public class Insert extends HttpServlet {
    
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
           response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();  
              
                ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String dirName =context.getRealPath("d://Photo/");
          try
        {  
            String name = request.getParameter("name");  
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
            String image = request.getParameter("image"); 
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            
            String fPath = "d:\\Photo\\" + image;
            System.out.println("insert! "+image);
         
            User u=new User();
            u.setName(name);
            u.setAddress(address);
            u.setPhone(phone);
            u.setImage(fPath);
            u.setPassword(password);  
           
            int i=UserDao.save(u);
        
           if(i>0)
            {  
            
                request.getRequestDispatcher("user-list.jsp").include(request, response);  
            }
            else
            {  
            out.println("Sorry! unable to insert record"); 
           
            }
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          
        out.close();  
    }

}
```

userdao code:

```
     public static int save(User u) throws FileNotFoundException{  
    int status=0;
    
    File file1 = null;
    FileInputStream fs = null, fs1=null;
    String img = u.getImage();
    System.out.println("userdao! "+img);
    file1 = new File(img);
    fs = new FileInputStream(file1);
    
    try{   
       Connection con=getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS);
            ps.setString(1, u.getName());
            ps.setString(2, u.getAddress());
            ps.setString(3, u.getPhone());
            ps.setObject(4, null);
            fs = new FileInputStream(img);
            System.out.println(fs);
            fs1=fs;
             ps.setBinaryStream(4, (InputStream)fs1, fs1.available());
            ps.setString(5, u.getPassword());
            
            status=ps.executeUpdate();  
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
    return status;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not really store images in the database. This is a very bad practice and the database will perform worst. Rather use this type of thing:

1. You take an image from the user and convert it into a byte array
2. You send the byte array to the server
3. Then the server converts the byte array to a file and you save the file to a directory
   of the server
4. And you save the location of the file as a string in the database

Now for sending to the client:

1. Get the file from the stored location
2. Convert it into a byte array
3. Send the byte array to the client

Comment: can u give me some example code for reference

Comment: i change the code and post it see it once... iam getting the error like this ............................insert! C:\fakepath\User.jpg
userdao! d:\Photo\C:\fakepath\User.jpg
SQLServerPreparedStatement:11
java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\Photo\C:\fakepath\User.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: Your file location is not correct. How can ac drive be on d drive.... :) :) What is your client side application? Javafx?

Comment: jsp web application project